# How to completely hide credentials and tokens in Azure Pipelines?

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-secrets

Is there a way to have the main Azure pipeline yaml file of a project in the developer's repo, but also completely hide credentials and access tokens from the developers? I mean even the variables names, so they can't reveal it using a step like this:

```
steps:
    - script: |
        echo SECRET_PASSWORD=$(SECRET_PASSWORD) > ~/secret_password.txt
      env:
        SECRET_PASSWORD: $(SECRET_PASSWORD)
```

And later read contents of: **~/secret_password.txt**
As long as they know the variables names they can uncover them in many ways.

How can I provide atomic actions (E.g 'push-package-to-server',  'authenticate-to-server', 'update-database-entry' etc.) that use my secret credentials/access-tokens but also unaccessible for others to read and find out the logic. Allow only to include/templating and use as an atmoic action with parameters/variables?

Comment: Consider using Azure Key Vault secrets. [Manage secrets in your server apps with Azure Key Vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/manage-secrets-with-azure-key-vault/).